# How to build a dictionary that map nodes to its degree in networkx2.1,python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx

what I try is here :

```
def comm_deg(G):
    nodes = G.nodes()
    A=nx.adj_matrix(G)
    deg_dict = {}
    n = len(nodes)  
    degree= A.sum(axis = 1)
    for i in range(n):
    deg_dict[nodes[i]] = degree[i,0]
    return deg_dict
```

it shows that KeyError: 0, I find both using  `nodes[]` `degree[,]` would occur this issue

here is the full error message:

```
> File "/Users/shaoyupei/Desktop/code/untitled1.py", line 25, in comm_deg
> deg_dict[nodes[i]] = degrees[i,0]

> File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/networkx/classes/reportviews.py", line 178, in __getitem__
> return self._nodes[n]

> KeyError: 0
```

Comment: Should not be degree[i]

Comment: @Serge I try  degree[I][0] also

Comment: can you give the full error message?  Also, can you tell us what version of networkx you have (try `nx.__version__`)

Comment: What do you want `degree[i,0]` to give?  What do you expect the `0` to mean?

Comment: @Joel hi Joel ,I already update ,I use  `degree[i,0]` since I find degree is a column vector ,my networkx is 2.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there's several issues here.

First, there's a better way to create a dict than what you're doing. 
 In fact it's basically already built in.  `G.degree` is already a dict-like object so that `G.degree[node]` will give the degree of `node`.

If you really want it to be a dict, the best way to do that is probably

```
deg_dict = dict(G.degree)
```

---

Now let's look at the error you're getting.  `G.nodes()` is not a list (it's also something dictlike).  So when you set `nodes=G.nodes()`, then `nodes` isn't a list.  Here `nodes[0]` trying to return the attributes of node `0` (and for what it's worth, if your nodes don't have any attributes `nodes[node]` will return an empty dict).  But  (I believe) `0` is not a node in your graph `G`.  So this is the meaning of your error message.

Also, as a general rule, if you ever do `n=len(x)` and then `for i in range(n):`, you almost always really want to do `for name in x:` or if you really need the index, you could do `for i, name in enumerate(x)`.

So if you want to use the approach you did,

```
for i, node in nodes:
    deg_dist[node] = degree[i]
```